# How to display 2nd ajax response in jquery dialog? Conflict between responses, first one displayed in div works, 2nd one only alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, coldfusion

Firebug and javascript alerts show the correct response and the dialog opens but **jqxhr** is not parsing. Jquery, jquery ui, javascript and css scripts are on the page but I left them out for space. I'm just learning this and need help with syntax and more.  Thanks!

**Updated AGAIN with additional suggestions. Using a ajax complete function finally got the 2nd ajax response to display in jquery dialog. Now only need help in parsing **jqxhr*** data into html form inputs. Thank you to all people who have contibuted ideas.*

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#StoreForm").dialog({autoOpen:false, width:500, height:500, modal:true});
 $('#content').css('min-height', '610px');
 $('#sidebar').css('min-height', '600px');

 $('a.storeCategories').unbind('click');
 $('a.storeCategories').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var stuff = ($(this).attr('href'));
  $.when($.post(stuff, function(response, status, xhr) {
  if(response.ROWCOUNT > 0) {  
  var s = [];  
  s.push("<table border='0'>");  
  for(var i=0; i<response.ROWCOUNT; i++) {  
//push can take multiple comma-separated strings, and it is very fast  
s.push("<tr><td><p>", response.DATA.ICON[i], "</p></td></tr>",  
       "<tr><td>", response.DATA.LABEL[i], "</td></tr>",  
       "<tr><td class=\"sel\">", response.DATA.PRICE[i], "</td>",
 "<td class=\"item\" display:  hidden>", response.DATA.PROD_SUPER_ID[i], "</td></tr>",  
       "<tr></tr>");  

}  
s.push("</table>");      
}      
else {  
s.push("Sorry, nothing matched your selection.");  
}  
//Now assemble the HTML by joining all the array elements together.  

$("#content").html(s.join(""));      

        //alert(s);


    $(".sel").unbind('click');
    $(".sel, #StoreForm").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#StoreForm").dialog('open');

    var valueSelected = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.item').text();

    //alert(valueSelected);//this alerts correctly

       var jqxhr = $.post('query/categories.cfc?method=getProductInfo&returnformat=json&
queryFormat=column',
    {productID: valueSelected},

    function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) { 




//$("#StoreForm").html("<b>Ray</b>")

//alert works below
jqxhr.always(function() { 

$('#StoreForm').html(data);

 });               
            })

        });    
    },"json"));



});

})    
DATA below: 
   {"ROWCOUNT":1,
"COLUMNS":[
"IMAGE_TYPE_REF_ID",
"ICON",
"PROD_SUPER_ID",
"COLOR_ATTRIB","SIZE_ATTRIB",
"SUPER_DESC","FULL_DESCRIPTION","PRICE","TAXABLE"],
"DATA {"IMAGE_TYPE_REF_ID": "large"],
"ICON"["http:/Apps/Product_Mgmt/large/necklace150.jpg"],
"PROD_SUPER_ID         
":["C-JAY00001"],"COLOR_ATTRIB":[true],"SIZE_ATTRIB":[true],"SUPER_DESC":["3 Stone
 Womens Quartz 23- inch Necklace"],"FULL_DESCRIPTION":
["This dainty three-drop quartz pendant
hangs  on a silver 23 inch chain. Presented in a small black satchel."],
"PRICE": [10.0000],"TAXABLE":  [true]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the elements that you're setting "h2" to exist before you do work on them. Try hand adding them, or queuing the ajax calls to happen synchronously one after the other is done in it's callback.

So basically take the $.post call you have here, and put it inside the callback of the other post or ajax, and then in `this` callback, keep what you have.

Comment: I've put the 2nd ajax call in the the 1st callback but the responses seem to be bumping into each other. Thanks for your help.

Comment: then you're doing something wrong.... one response should lead to data for the second call, and that response should have all your final data. If one is inside the other, and a callback of a callback, then it will work.

Comment: I'm getting all my final data in an alert(response) for the second ajax post. I haven't been able yet to put it into the page. I get: "Sorry, no selection." in my dialog. Here is a link to the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/suewe/ta6YW/116/

Comment: Finally got data in ajax complete now how to put it into html. I have updated code on page and link. Thanks

Comment: @Sue we really have to work on your separation of data layers... however, to answer your question, it looks like you've started down the correct path, but I can't get the fiddle to... fiddle.

Comment: however, my thought for the 'click', I suggest you change it to an 'on' instead so it watches for DOM changes... like so: `$('body').on('click', '.sel, #StoreForm', function(response){/*data action*/});`

Comment: Thanks very much, for the advice. Do you know of a good resource for learning how to design the structure of jquery or javascript so I can figure out the data layers. I'm definitely a novice trying to learn this stuff.

Comment: I more meant, separating your HTML, JavaScript, and is that... no... I really hope that's not ColdFusion. Anyways, it would be impossible to fiddle the way you want because it's cross domain, if you set up a jsonp service though we may be able to solve your problem. (Google 'JSONP services'+*whateverlanguageyoureusing*)

Comment: Hi,ood humor, yes, it's coldfusion.

Comment: Hi, good humor, yes, it's coldfusion. I'll try to figure out how to use the jsFiddle. I read the instructions. I put my updated script there: http://jsfiddle.net/ta6YW/121/

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem and that is setting the id=\"item\". HTML id's must be unique. Better to set a class instead class="\item\", then do:

```
$(".item").click(function(e) {
    var valueSelected = $(this).html();
    ...rest of your code...
}
```

Also, as a side note, you'll get better performance putting together that table string in your first call by pushing your string fragments onto an array, then using array.join() to blit them out to HTML like so:

```
if(response.ROWCOUNT > 0) {
    var s = [];
    s.push("<table border='1'>");
    for(var i=0; i<response.ROWCOUNT; i++) {
        //push can take multiple comma-separated strings, and it is very fast
        s.push("<tr><td>", response.DATA.ICON[i], "</td></tr>",
               "<tr><td>", response.DATA.LABEL[i], "</td></tr>",
               "<tr><td>", response.DATA.PRICE[i], "</td></tr>",
               "<tr><td id=\"item\">", response.DATA.PROD_SUPER_ID[i], "</td></tr>");

    }
    s.push("</table>");    
}    
else {
    s.push("Sorry, nothing matched your selection.");
}
//Now assemble the HTML by joining all the array elements together.
$("#content").html(s.join(""));
```

When doing string concatenation, pushing strings onto an array then dumping them out by joining them is so much faster than concatenating; especially when you have lots of strings to concatenate.

Comment: Thanks, I revised my 1st ajax post using class instead of id in  the table code with your suggestions and it works good. Now the only thing not working is the second ajax response. I have tried lots of things but it isn't displaying in the dialog window yet.

Comment: The ajax response in the 2nd post works correctly, it's the display of the response in the dialog that isn't right yet.

Comment: How would I create an image tag as part of the string above.  , "<img src=\"response.DATA.ICON[i]\" />", this isn't working? Thanks

Comment: Got it:  , "<img src=" + response.DATA.ICON[i] + " />",

Answer (score 0):

The reason the response does not show up in the dialog is that the selectors `$( '#oneitem > h2' )` and `$( '#oneitem > p' )` result in no elements, because the element with id `oneitem` has no children. If you want to add `h2` and `p` elements to the dialog, you'll need code more like:

```
$('<h2></h2>').html(response.DATA.FULL_DESCRIPTION[i]).appendTo('#oneitem');
$('<p></p>').html(response.DATA.PROD_SUPER_ID[i]).appendTo('#oneitem');
$('<p></p>').html(response.DATA.PRICE[i]).appendTo('#oneitem');
```

Here's a sample of escaped JSON, which works in the console:

```
{"ROWCOUNT":1,"COLUMNS":["IMAGE_TYPE_REF_ID","ICON","PROD_SUPER_ID","COLOR_ATTRIB","SIZE_ATTRIB","SUPER_DESC","FULL_DESCRIPTION","PRICE","TAXABLE"],"DATA":{"IMAGE_TYPE_REF_ID": "large","ICON":["http:/Apps/Product_Mgmt/large/necklace150.jpg"],"PROD_SUPER_ID":["C-JAY00001"],"COLOR_ATTRIB":[true],"SIZE_ATTRIB":[true],"SUPER_DESC":["3 Stone Women\'s Quartz 23-inch Necklace"],"FULL_DESCRIPTION":["This dainty three-drop quartz pendant hangs on a silver 23 inch chain. Presented in a small black satchel."],"PRICE":[10.0000],"TAXABLE":[true]}}
```

Comment: This makes sense and I made the change but still no display in the dialog window. Maybe it's confused with the first ajax 'response'? or I am not parsing the response correctly. The dialog opens but nothing in it. Thanks, I looked at your blog and it has a lot of good information.

Comment: One thing that might help debug this is to take some sample output and put it up on http://jsfiddle.net/ There might be something in the actual HTML (after ColdFusion has rendered it) which could be causing problems...

Comment: I looked at this json response form coldfusion in jsFiddle and it said ROWCOUNT invalid label: (I put data sample above at end of the original question.) In JSON Visualization it says it's valid. Somehow the 2 responses are conflicting or the syntax is wrong. I can use firefox for ajax debugging but how to debug the jquery and jquery-ui? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It might be the unescaped single quote in the JSON that's causing the problem, so I pasted the escaped JSON in my answer. I also ran your script through http://jsbeautifier.org/ and I see what the issue is. I didn't notice that your ajax requests were nested. Try changing the names of the arguments in the second ajax call from `(response, status, xhr)` to `(data, textStatus, jqXhr)`. You'll need to rename the rest of your variables too.

Comment: I've made changes and it has helped. The 2nd response is not displaying yet. Thanks